# Can anyone help me with my C code in this Visual Studio scanf error C6031

Tags: c, visual-studio, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2, num3;

    printf("Enter First Number");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter First Number");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("Enter First Number");
    scanf("%d", &num3);

    printf("The numbers in  reverse order : %d %d d% ", num1, num2, num3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2, num3;

    printf("Enter First Number");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter second Number");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("Enter third Number");
    scanf("%d", &num3);

    printf("The numbers in  reverse order : %d %d %d ", num3, num2, num1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: printf("The numbers in  reverse order : %d %d d% ", num1, num2, num3);   the error is here